# Create a package with optional mode and key values

Tags: package-writing, optional-arguments, xparse

I'm trying to create a package with three options as follows:

```
\usepackage[swpl]{mypack}
```

`swpl` option provides the environment

```
\begin{myexample}[forced bracketed options]...\end{myexample}
```

available for all xelatex/latex

```
\usepackage[tcb]{mypack}
```

`tcb` option provides the same environment name (with different definition)

```
\begin{myexample}[other forced bracketed options]...\end{myexample}
```

available for latex/xelatex and the third option:

```
\usepackage[pdf,swpl]{mypack} or \usepackage[pdf,tcb]{mypack}
```

provides the same environment name (with other definition) available for (pdf/lua/xe)latex. I'm triying to adapt [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146308/kvoptions-and-conditional-environment) for this...but I did not succeed. If anyone can help me with a skeleton (using `kvoptions` or `pgfkeys`) I'd appreciate it. I was unable to add `[requiered]` for the `myexample` environment and boolean option for `swpl` and `tcb`.

PD: Using the same environment name because the first option uses `showexpl` and the second option `tcolorbox` for verbatim.

Comment: Related: [How to add optional arguments to a package I'm writing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106804/5764); [How can I make a package that accepts an optional argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12631/5764)

Comment: Consider `l3keys2e` (I think that's what it's called; I'm mobile. Everyone should feel free to correct me `:)`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the description I assume that definition of the environment `mypack` does not need to be changed after the package is loaded. Then two switches and classical options will do:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypack}{2014/04/17 My package}

\newif\ifmypack@swpl % swpl: true, tcb: false
\newif\ifmypack@pdf  % option pdf

\DeclareOption{swpl}{\mypack@swpltrue}
\DeclareOption{tcb}{\mypack@swplfalse}
\DeclareOption{pdf}{\mypack@pdftrue}

\ProcessOptions* % process options in the order they are given
```

Then the switches `\ifmypack@swpl` and `\ifmypack@pdf` can be used for the implementation of environment `myexample`, e.g:

```
\ifmypack@swpl
  % code for option "swpl"
\else
  % code for option "tcb"
\fi
```

Comment: Many thanks, I now define the [...] mandatory for the environment, `xparse` maybe?.

Answer (score 4):

This is a rewrite of [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172011/) using the new option processing facilities in recent versions of LaTeX.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023-01-12]
\ProvidesPackage{mypack}{2023/04/17 My package}

\newif\ifmypack@swpl % swpl: true, tcb: false
\newif\ifmypack@pdf  % option pdf

\DeclareKeys [mypack] {%
  swpl.if = mypack@swpl,
  tcb.ifnot = mypack@swpl,
  pdf.if = mypack@pdf,
  swpl.usage = load,
  tcb.usage = load,
  pdf.usage = load,
}
\ProcessKeyOptions [mypack]
```

Comment: Great answer, can you give an alternative version more `expl3` for new users?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. I deliberately avoided `expl3` in this precisely to make it more intelligible to new users! Obviously, if you use `expl3`, you can use that in conjunction with this.