# How to access class boolean macro from main .tex document

Tags: luatex, kvoptions

I'm trying to access the boolean macro I defined with my class. Whenever I access the boolean within the class, it works fine. However, if try to access it from the main document (using the same code), I get an `Undefined control sequence. \ifMY`.

testclass.cls

```tex
%! Class = testclass

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2023/11/29 Minimum Working Example Class]

\LoadClass[t,xcolor={x11names},aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=MY,prefix=MY@}
\DeclareBoolOption{optA}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\newcommand{\test}{\ifMY@optA
true
\else
false
\fi}
```

test.tex

```tex
% Preamble
\documentclass[optA=false]{testclass}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Works fine.}
    \test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Has an error.}
    \ifMY@optA
    true
    \else
    false
    \fi
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I use the if within the document, or would I have to create a command in the class, similar to `\test`?

Comment: for a new class I would strongly suggest that you use the new Key option handling provided by the latex format  rather than  `kvoptions` see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693340/1090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` are not allowed in the main document for the macro name. Take a look this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do). To make it work, several options you can do.

1. Get rid of the `@` sign in prefix.
2. Add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` before and after the frame env.
3. Copy the \ifMY@optA command to make a version without `@`.

I prefer the last option.

Here is the code for testclass.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2023/11/29 Minimum Working Example Class]

\LoadClass[t,xcolor={x11names},aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=MY,prefix=MY@}
\DeclareBoolOption{optA}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\let\ifmyoptA\ifMY@optA

\newcommand{\test}{\ifMY@optA
true
\else
false
\fi}
```

Here is the code for main document:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[optA=false]{testclass}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Works fine.}
    \test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Has an error.}
    \ifmyoptA
    true
    \else
    false
    \fi
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]